# Error: EL1004E: Method call: Method rename(java.lang.String,java.lang.String) cannot be found on type com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp$2

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-transactions, spring-el

I'm trying to rename files in a remote sftp server at the end of a transaction and using Spring Boot Integration. In the official [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/transactions.html) they provide examples using TransactionSynchronizationFactory with SpEL expressions similar to:

```
    @Bean
public TransactionSynchronizationFactory transactionSynchronizationFactory(){

    ExpressionEvaluatingTransactionSynchronizationProcessor processor = new ExpressionEvaluatingTransactionSynchronizationProcessor();

    SpelExpressionParser spelParser = new SpelExpressionParser();
    processor.setAfterCommitExpression(spelParser.parseRaw(
            "payload.renameTo(headers['file_remoteDirectory']+'/'+headers['file_remoteFile'] ,headers['file_remoteDirectory']+'/'+headers['file_remoteFile']+'.PASSED')"));

    processor.setAfterRollbackExpression(spelParser.parseRaw(
            "payload.renameTo(headers['file_remoteDirectory']+'/'+headers['file_remoteFile'] ,headers['file_remoteDirectory']+'/'+headers['file_remoteFile']+'.FAILED')"));

    
    return new DefaultTransactionSynchronizationFactory(processor);
}
```

In my implementation, I don't use a *File* object, but an *InputStream* as payload in the sftpAdapter. The transaction is working, but the expression evaluation is failing in *afterCommit* and *afterRollBack* operation and the files are not being renamed.
I'm having below error from that method *org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression#getValue(org.springframework.expression.EvaluationContext, java.lang.Object)* :

> EL1004E: Method call: Method rename(java.lang.String,java.lang.String) cannot be found on type com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp$2

Here is my implementation:

```
    @Bean
@InboundChannelAdapter(channel = sftp-inChannel",
        poller = @Poller(value = "pollerMetadata"),
        autoStartup = "${sftp.autoStartup:true}")
public MessageSource<InputStream> ftpMessageSource() {
    SftpStreamingMessageSource source = new SftpStreamingMessageSource(sftpRemoteFileTemplate());
    source.setRemoteDirectory(path);
    source.setFilter(chainFilter());
    source.setMaxFetchSize(maxFetchSize);
    return source;
}


@Bean
public PollerMetadata pollerMetadata() {
    return Pollers.fixedRate(delayInMillisec)
            .maxMessagesPerPoll(maxFetchSize)
            .advice(transactionInterceptor())
            .transactionSynchronizationFactory(transactionSynchronizationFactory())
            .transactional()
            .get();
}



@Bean
public TransactionSynchronizationFactory transactionSynchronizationFactory(){

    ExpressionEvaluatingTransactionSynchronizationProcessor processor = new ExpressionEvaluatingTransactionSynchronizationProcessor();

    SpelExpressionParser spelParser = new SpelExpressionParser();
    processor.setAfterCommitExpression(spelParser.parseRaw(
            "payload.rename(headers['file_remoteDirectory']+'/'+headers['file_remoteFile'] ,headers['file_remoteDirectory']+'/'+headers['file_remoteFile']+'.PASSED')"));

    processor.setAfterRollbackExpression(spelParser.parseRaw(
            "payload.rename(headers['file_remoteDirectory']+'/'+headers['file_remoteFile'] ,headers['file_remoteDirectory']+'/'+headers['file_remoteFile']+'.FAILED')"));

    
    return new DefaultTransactionSynchronizationFactory(processor);
}
```

I can see the class *ChannelSftp* has a *.rename(String, String)* method and is the payload's type, but it seems like SpEL is not able to see the casting from GenericMessage to ChannelSftp, hence can't see the .rename(String, String) method.
I spent a day trying to find something in the documentation w/out success, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is here: `com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp$2`. Pay attention to that `$2`. This is already not a `ChannelSftp`, but an internal `InputStream` for the remote file. And that's exactly what `SftpStreamingMessageSource` is producing. It does not return files, neither `ChannelSftp`. You cannot call `rename()` on the `InputStream`.

Consider to use a special `IntegrationMessageHeaderAccessor.CLOSEABLE_RESOURCE` header instead. This one is an instance of the `org.springframework.integration.file.remote.session.Session` which already has a required `rename(String pathFrom, String pathTo)` method. But again: this one is going to do that for the remote file:

```
 processor.setAfterCommitExpression(spelParser.parseRaw(
            "headers.closeableResource.rename(headers['file_remoteDirectory']+'/'+headers['file_remoteFile'] ,headers['file_remoteDirectory']+'/'+headers['file_remoteFile']+'.PASSED')"));
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that was it. I'm only interested in renaming the remote files.